# Store byte contents in S3

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, amazon-s3

I need to save binary (`byte[]`) contents (PDF file) to S3.

I don't want to have a hard copy existing in HDD, pdf is being generated in the fly and then it needs to be sent to S3.

Java AWS SDK `AmazonS3.putObject()` requires `File` type in method signature, how can I pass my binary contents directly without saving it to hard drive?

Comment: you can use a temporary file.
`File tempFile = File. createTempFile("hello", ".tmp");`
please have a look at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-

Comment: How are you producing the PDF file? Are you doing the conversion to `byte[]` on your own (ie, by passing `ByteArrayOutputStream`), or does the library do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The SDK offers method that take `InputStream` and `ObjectMetadata` instead of `File`. For example there is [`putObject(String bucketName, String key, InputStream input, ObjectMetadata metadata)`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html#putObject-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.io.InputStream-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.ObjectMetadata-).

Use one of the provided methods and supply `ByteArrayInputStream` if you don't want to create files.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method for aws file storage.

```
PutObjectResult         putObject(String bucketName, String key, InputStream input, ObjectMetadata metadata)
```

Aws also provides the following overloaded method to use based upon the suitability.

```
PutObjectResult         putObject(PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest)
PutObjectResult         putObject(String bucketName, String key, File file)
PutObjectResult         putObject(String bucketName, String key, String content)
```

You can convert byte[] to InputStream and you can pass in the above method. Refer below the javadocs for aws:

[Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3.html)

[PutObjectRequest](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/PutObjectRequest.html)